# How to guess gaps in spectroscopy

Tags: spectroscopy

i have two spectrometer chip but these have wavelength spaces.
(like 610nm, 680nm, 730nm, 760nm, 810nm, 860nm and 450nm, 500nm, 550nm, 570nm, 600nm, 650nm)

it makes gap for example 510nm is between 500nm and 550nm. is there any way to guess or calculate it?